# Is there a word like "hobbyistically"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say "I do this as a hobby", but in fewer words, like "I hobyistically do this". However, [all](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=hobbyistically) [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hobbyistically) [tell me](http://www.oed.com/noresults?q=hobbyistically) this isn't a word. **Is there such a word?**

Comment: I do it “for fun” - six letters. Pretty short.

Comment: You want to do it in fewer words but more characters and more syllables??  You can certainly say "hobbyistically" if you wish, and it would *probably* be understood by most listeners, but it is not a dictionary "word" and is not likely to become one.

Comment: @HotLicks yes... It's an odd requirement, I know XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some other options here:

- **avocationally**: A *vocation* is a calling, commonly used to indicate a main occupation one is particularly suited for. Negating, an *avocation* is something that is not one's main calling, like a hobby or a past-time.
- **recreationally**: instead of saying you do something for *fun*, you can use this word. A recreation is something one does to refresh oneself from a main occupation.

Comment: Oh recreationally sounds perfect!

Comment: The only reservation I have is that a hobby is usually an activity that is undertaken with a degree of enthusiasm, application and organisation. For instance one can play a musical instrument, build motorcars or run competitively as a hobby but one cannot wander aimlessly in parks as a hobby. All hobbies are recreation but not all recreational activities can be described as hobbies.

Comment: Potentially - it all depends. Plenty of people do have a hobby of simply taking a walk, observing the world around them. In fact, the word *hobby* [comes from](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=hobby) hobbyhorse, a toy that doesn't go anywhere, much like wandering aimlessly in a park. Likewise, a *recreation* is something one does to [refresh oneself](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=recreation), arguably from a directed, applied, or organized activity. At the end of the day, it depends on how the OP defines *hobby* in their use-case.

Answer (score 3):

What's a word? One might think that a conservative answer would be any string of letters defined in a dictionary. But lexicographers are sometimes mistaken and include their errors, which other lexicographers have been known to copy those errors. How do you feel about obsolete words, particularly those not used in centuries? How about *hapax legomena*? How about obsolete *hapax legomena* not used for centuries? Even if we ignore these exceptions, dictionaries don't necessarily list all words derived by standard rules. Space is always a premium in dictionaries.

Let's start with *hobby*, surely a word (and dictionary heading) for a type of activity. English uses the suffix *-ism* to denote a movement and the suffix *-ist* to denote a practitioner. Thus we have *socialism* and *socialist*. Can we likewise consider *hobbyism* and *hobbyist* as words? The *OED* does, finding first written examples in 1846 and 1871, respectively.

As *socialism* begets *socialistic*, can we consider *hobbyistic* a word? If so, we're not alone. The Ngram viewer finds the following from [*The Art Of Putzing: Your Guide To A Guilt-Free Retirement Of Puttering*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WzCcDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT75&dq=%22hobbyistic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI4bTUg8jRAhWm4IMKHfsBCVUQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22hobbyistic%22&f=false) by M Decker and J Hickey:

> Along with the naturally **hobbyistic**, such persons need to be avoided.

As *mystic* is to *mystical*, is there a next step to *hobbyistical*? Christopher Kane thinks so in an online offering he labels

> [A hobbyistical blog](https://github.com/christopherkane)

And I think we all know what Mr. Kane means by that description. English creates adverbs from adjectives ending in *-al*, so is there any reason not to recognize the adverb *hobbyistically*? The google will tell you whether anyone else agrees, but even if your search comes up empty, how is that adverbial construct, standardly-formed from a recognized adjective, not a word?